# WordPress Admin Loging 404 Error re .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, openshift

I've a WordPress site hosted on OpenShift and I can't access my admin login page.  When going to the /wp-admin or /wp-login.php pages I get a 404 / "page not found" error.

WordPress forum suggestions have advised deleting the .htaccess file at the app's root and the app shout reset the file granting me access.  Because OpenShift uses a different directory structure, I can't find the correct .htaccess file specific to WordPress.

Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 0):

Your .htaccess file should still be located with the core wordpress files, are you accessing the server via sftp? Are you viewing hidden files?

Should be located in /app-root/data/current/

Comment: Yes, I'm using SFTP and have set FileZilla to "Force showing hidden files".  I'm missing the path /app-root/data/current/.  I can access the app's root, where wp-config.php can be found, at /app-root/runtime/repo/php.

Comment: OpenShift advises (here https://github.com/openshift/wordpress-example) that the .htaccess file should be accessible at .openshift/config/. This path seems missing from my installation. I've search vis SFTP and SSH for the path and .htaccess file and haven't found either. Any advice?